# Possible corrupt NTFS System (Windows Files still accessible via Ubuntu)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, password

a few days ago I had to replace my motherboard because it was acting up and not letting my Lenovo laptop boot. When replacing the motherboard I took out the HDD and connected it to my friend's laptop to salvage important files. In doing so, I had to change some of the admin/user permission settings on the HDD so that it would allow me to copy the files over. After doing so, I put the HDD back to my Lenovo and after seeing the normal dual boot menu show up, I selected Windows only to find out that when entering the user password it would say the password's incorrect. I tried entering the PIN and doing a finger scan but nothing works. What I find odd is that the left-click and right-click buttons also don't work on my trackpad when trying to log onto Windows (they work fine in Ubuntu).

After that, I went on Ubuntu and tried to access my Windows filesystem through there but got the following error:
    "Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sda2: Command-line `mount 
    "/mnt/16B0BB6AB0BB4ECD"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The 
    disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
    Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
    Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
    The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state."
but I managed to fix the issue by going to disks, selecting 'Mount Options' on the Windows partition, and suffixing ',ro' at the end of 'nosuid,nodevnofail,x-gvfs-show'.

However, despite being able to access my Windows files through Linux I still encountered the same problems when booting into Windows. I tried booting into Ubuntu and running chntpw -l SAM to reset the password but got the error 
   "root@sam:/media/sda2/Windows/System32/config# chntpw -i SAM
    chntpw version 1.00 140201, (c) Petter N Hagen
    openHive(SAM) failed: Read-only file system, trying read-only
    openHive(): read error: : Read-only file system
    chntpw: Unable to open/read a hive, exiting.."

I'm guessing I've corrupted my NTFS partition. Any advice on what I should do next to boot into Windows would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Preferred approach**: In general, an ntfs partition should be checked and repaired by the MS Windows disk checking tools. If anyway possible, **connect your SSD to another working Windows install, and have it checked there**.

**Backup approach**: If you do not have the possibility to connect the SSD to another Windows system, you may try checking and repairing it in your linux session. *This may either work or make matters worse, so make sure you safeguard your personal data before attempting this*. If mounted, then unmount the partition first. Then **use the ntfsfix utility**:

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/###`

where `/dev/###` should be replaced by the actual device name of the ntfs partition. You can find the name of that partition in the output of

`lsblk`

This might be enough to make your Windows system bootable again, after which you can check the volume again using the Windows tools. *It might, however, not work, or even make the situation worse.* Thus, before doing that, make certain your backup of the data is up to date.

Comment: Don't use ntfsfix, use chkdsk from a Windows platform.

Comment: @heynnema That is what I recommend i n my answer as the first and best/safest option indeed.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough... ntfsfix can do more damage than good. It does nothing for directory/file structure repairs, but only wipes the hibernation/page file, and when returning to Windows, the current state of Windows is not restored, and as such, you can loose data/edits.

Comment: Loosing data is not the issue: that is why the user should, as he did, safeguard personal data. At least there is a chance that with a semi-fixed system he can get into Windows again, and then  further check the disk from within Windows. I fully agree that connecting the disk to a Windows system is by far preferred, and that ntfsfix might make things worse rather than better. I will emphasize this more in my answer.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I saved all my data and would like to reformat windows/reset it through Ubuntu if possible. is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Yes, but that is another question.